# Python: Continuing asking for input until given valid response

Tags: python, loops, validation, random

I'm working on a random number game and have a code that works for the purpose. However I would love for the programme to say something like "That is not a valid input" when the player enters a number that is less than 1 or larger than 10.
Is there an easy way to do it?
I tried a quick fix with an if else statement, which did not work.

This is the code I have so far:

```
from random import randint

def validateNumber(number):
    return 1 <= number <= 10

game_1 = randint(1, 10)
while True:
    is_valid = False
    while not is_valid:
        try:
            number_in = int(input("Guess which number from 1-10 that will come up: "))
            is_valid = validateNumber(number_in)
        except ValueError:            
            pass
    if number_in == game_1:
        print(f"The result was {game_1}. Congrats!")
        break
    else:
        print(f"The result was {game_1}. Try again")
        game_1 = randint(1, 10)
```

Is there an easy way to loop it to ask for a new number when the players input is invalid?

All answers appreciated!
(And sorry if this is a very easy question, I'm fairly new to Python and right now out of ideas even after looking at some of the existing questions on here)

Comment: `if not is_valid: print("That is not a valid input")`